# Access Continuous form based on recordest made with VBA (fill the form fields)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've prepared recordset and open form with this.
The form works with recordset - quantities of records in the form is the same like on the recordset.

Problem:

I have absolutely no idea how to display the recordset results in the form fields.
I know one way - create an assistant table but I would like to avoid it.

Any idea please ?

```
Dim rst As Object
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

....


With rst

        .Fields.Append "date", 7
        .Fields.Append "index", 3

    End With

rst.Open

......

Set Forms!Form1.Recordset = rst
```

Comment: I have never seen this method. Why are you using it?

Comment: My preliminary testing indicates need controls on form with ControlSource set for those field names. However, since the fields have no data, the controls are Null. There is only one record and control does not accept data entry. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Correction, there are no records created with the limited code you posted.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't just create a table, and have the continues form set to that table? That takes ZERO code. It not clear why this is a particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interesting,

I have to create recordset.
I need to make some calculation between two table and only way I find it is with vba (no way with sql).

Anyway it shoud be a way to open form with recordset.

You cane create a simple continuous form ("Form1") with one blank field.
The code below is for loading form.

As you can see you'll open the form with 4 blank field.
How to put code result (0,1,2,3) into form fields ?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rst As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rst.Fields.Append "Field_1", 3
rst.Open

For i = 0 To 3

    With rst
        .AddNew
        ![Field_1] = i
        .Update
    End With
    
    Debug.Print i
    
Next

Set Forms!Form1.Recordset = rst

Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```